# How can I get a total count of an int field in a List?

Tags: c#

I have this class, variable and method used to populate it:

```
public class CategoryGroupWordCountVM : ObservableProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsToggled { get; set; }
    public int TotalWordCount { get; set; }
}

List<CategoryGroupWordCountVM> categoryGroups;

categoryGroups = AS.dm.GetCategoryGroupWithWordCount();
```

How can I get a total of all of the values of the TotalWordCount field using LINQ or any other method if it can be done as a one liner. I know I can do this with a "for" loop but hoping for something that could be all in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx)**,

```
var sum = categoryGroups.Sum(x=>x.TotalWordCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do LINQ to Objects and the use LINQ to calculate the totals:

```
decimal totalSum = (from od in categoryGroups
select od.TotalWordCount ).Sum();
```

You can also use lambda-expressions to do this, which is a bit "cleaner".

```
decimal totalSum  = categoryGroups.Sum(x => x.TotalWordCount);
```